# What are the effects of angle of attack on turbines in composed delta wings with jets in upper side?

Tags: turbine, propulsion, delta-wing, blended-wing

: a layperson doubt. What would happen during take-off and landing of a machine as Boeing X-48, because of the high angle of attack, the steep attitude of the airplane: would this difficult air supply to turbines?

Comment: Very little air is supplied to the turbine for cooling and has quite a stable pressures because of the circuit and regulators. Turbine main flow is hot combustion gas from combustion chamber. So direct answer to your answer is "unaffected"

Comment: I suspect this question is more directed at the overall performance of such a jet engine installation during high AOA. Compressor stall in this regime would certainly be a design consideration.